# Natural killers cells in insects/ arthropods

Tags: entomology, immunology

I'm wondering if someone knowns anything about Natural Killer cells in insects or other Arthropods. Do they exist or are their any similar cells of the innate immune system that someone knows of? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: should be easy to find some information on google for that straightforward question? where else have you tried looking?

Comment: I tried google and more specific scientific literature (concerning the immune system of insects, crustacea and drosophila), I find elaborate descriptions of the innate arthropod immune system, but NKcells (or cells that perform similar functions) were never mentioned

Comment: NK cells are desinated adaptive immune cells now. There was a [discussion](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52288/why-are-natural-killer-cells-considered-cells-of-innate-immunity) on this topic some while ago.